# Cypress - user defined function returns the wrong value

Tags: typescript, testing, automation, cypress

I have two user defined functions in Cypress to use for login.

Here's the code:

```
static GetUserGUID(clientId: string): string {

    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };

    cy
        .request({ method: 'GET', url: `api/v1/Administration/User?UserTypeId=1&ClientId=` + clientId, headers })
        .then((resp) => {

            const userObject: UserObject = resp.body;
            const userData = userObject.users[0]
            return userData.id

        })

    return "User not found"

}
```

This always returns user not found.
I've been reading about cypress promises, commands and it really is a mess.

How would I get userdata.id from here?
Thanks

Comment: You are returning two things from your function ?

Comment: You would need to use `Cypress.Promise` and return values with `resolve` and `reject`. Read more here: https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/promise#Syntax

Comment: @AlapanDas 
Yes, function should exit at the first return, it doesn't however.

Comment: @Jonah 
Can you show me an example on the above written code maybe?

Answer (score 2):

As cypress commands are asynchronous, you cannot return a user id string directly. It's possible to return a `Chainable` with that string instead:

```js
static GetUserGUID(clientId: string): Chainable<string> {

    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };

    return cy
        .request({ method: 'GET', url: `api/v1/Administration/User?UserTypeId=1&ClientId=` + clientId, headers })
        .then((resp) => {

            const userObject: UserObject = resp.body;
            const userData = userObject.users[0]
            return userData.id

        })
}
```

Use it in your test as follows:

```js
GetUserGUID("myId").then(userId => {
   // you get the 'userId' as a string here.
})
```

Comment: What if there is no user?

Comment: I suppose the initial question is about cypress asynchronous computation model and not about handling corner cases. It's not a problem to add the logic inside `then` callback

Comment: this does work now, but for some reason, i have to chain multiple commands in order for values not to be undefined, example:

Comment: could you provide an example?